# Obj-C, why aren't my getter and setters working?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a problem with my getters and settings, they aren't being called. I thought I understood how they worked, but it looks like I have a problem...

I know I'm not initializing the DateRangeController view before I use the select button, but knowing its nil I can set values in viewDidLoad. If I do have to initialize it how do I set the nib file etc ?

This is my parent screen, where I'm setting values and getting values

```
@interface PieChartViewController : UIViewController {
    DateRangeController *nextController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) DateRangeController *nextController;
@implementation PieChartViewController
@synthesize nextController;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([nextController StartDate] == nil) {
        [nextController setStartDate:[NSDate date]];
    }

    // DBStartDate returns nil and yes convertNSDateToDBStringDate works !
    NSString* DBStartDate = [General convertNSDateToDBStringDate:
       [nextController StartDate]];
}
- (void) selectRangeButtonPressed {
    nextController = [[[DateRangeController alloc] 
        initWithNibName:@"DateRange" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    nextController.title = @"Date Range";   
}
```

Heres my selection / child screen.

```
@interface DateRangeController : UIViewController  {
NSDate *returnStartDate;
}
-(NSDate*) StartDate;
-(void)setStartDate:(NSDate*) value;
@end
@implementation DateRangeController
-(NSDate*) StartDate {
   return returnStartDate;
}
-(void)setStartDate:(NSDate*) value {
    if (value != returnStartDate) {
       [value retain];
       [returnStartDate release];
       returnStartDate = value;
       NSLog(@"StartDate=%@", returnStartDate);
    }
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)
       nibBundleOrNil {
   if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
       // Custom initialization
       returnStartDate = nil;
   }
   return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
   [returnStartDate release];
}
```

Comment: I think you missed **@property (nonatomic, retain) DateRangeController *nextController;**

Comment: You should really keep your functions and variables start with lower case. Only classes should start with uppercase. Code ethics :)

Comment: Sorry @Simon, forgot to paste that in above, I do have that. @MiRAGe good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try comparing "value" with the isEqualToDate - function instead of the "!=" - operator:

```
if(![value isEqualToDate: returnStartDate]) { ...}
```

EDIT: If you need the nextController to store the startDate in the viewWillAppear, you should initialize it there (or, even better, in the viewDidLoad) and not in the buttonPressed - Method, before assigning the startDate.

Comment: The purpose of a setter of a retain property is to replace *pointers*, so the use of `!=` to compare `NSDate *` pointers is correct here.

Comment: I could do that, but it doesn't call the != line anyway.

Comment: @Jules: From your code it seems that the nextController is allocated too late. You would have to press the button and re-load the view (thus calling viewwillappear again) to get any results. Try initializing it in the viewwillappear and see if the getters/setters are called.